# Ubuntu is very unstable on my PC

Tags: 12.04

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS which is very unstable on my PC. When I shut down my PC it asks for a confirmation but it doesn't respond when I click on shut down. I finally have to press the reset button.

I have installed all available updates but when I play a DVD or 3gp, mp4 videos from a movie player it asks to install missing plugins. However, when I click on the install button, it shows an error message that it could not be installed. Then, I tried to install `gstreamer` from terminal and it asked for a password but when I tried to type the password it wasn't shown on the screen. Please help.

Comment: "i tried to type password but its not typing in the terminal" -- for security it doesn't display any characters when you type the password, but it IS accepting the keyboard input.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you open a new question for the second issue.

Answer (score 0):

1) Press Ctrl + ALt + T

2) Enter "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras" without quotation marks.

3) Press Enter and wait for it to install.

This fixes this problem ->

"I have installed all available updates but when I play a DVD or 3gp, mp4 videos from a movie player it asks to install missing plugins. However, when I click on the install button, it shows an error message that it could not be installed."